# How to update size of QWidgets w inside [ QMainWindow [ QScrollArea [ QWidget [ w, w, ... ] ] ] ]?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtwidgets

I'm using Qt 5.15 with C++17. I have a hierarchy of Widgets like hinted in the title:

```
MainWindow : QMainWindow
->centralWidget() = QScrollArea
   ->widget() = QWidget
      ->layout() = QVBoxLayout
         ->children() = [
            InnerWidget,
            InnerWidget,
            InnerWidget,
            ...
            ]
```

with `InnerWidget.children() = [ QLabel, QLabel ]`.
I have set `InnerWidget::setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum)` inside `InnerWidget`'s constructor.

The `QLabels` inside `InnerWidget` are initialized with some `QPixmap img` like

```
label->setPixmap(img);
label->setFixedSize(img.size());
```

---

This all works fine, however now I added an option to zoom all the pixmaps to the `MainWindow`'s menubar. I connect to a signal `MainWindow::zoom_inner(..`, which itself calls `InnerWidget::zoom(..` on every `InnerWidget`, which resizes the images / labels like this:

```
auto scaled = img.scaled(img.size() * factor);
label->setPixmap(scaled);
label->setFixedSize(scaled.size());
```

Finally I update the size of the `MainWindow` by finding the maximum `InnerWidget.frameGeometry().width()` (= `inner_max_width`) and calling

```
void MainWindow::zoom_inner() {
  // ...
  setMaximumWidth(inner_max_width + centralWidget()->verticalScrollBar()->width() + 3);
  resize(maximumWidth(), size().height());
}
```

---

Now after calling `MainWindow::zoom_inner(..`, the window seems to resize to the correct size, as do the `QLabel`'s inside the `InnerWidget`'s. However, the `InnerWidget`'s themselves do **not resize** at all, they just stay the same size as before and I have no idea why. I tried calling many combinations of

```
adjustSize();
update();
layout()->update();
updateGeometry();
```

on any of the `MainWindow`,`QScrollArea`,`InnerWidget` but nothing happens.. even calling `InnerWidget::resize(new_size)` has no effect. Clearly `InnerWidget::sizeHint()` gives the correct value, because the `MainWindow` size after `MainWindow::zoom(..` is correct. So why do the `InnerWidget`'s refuse to resize to fit the `QLabel`'s, even though sizePolicy is set to `QSizePolicy::Minimum`?

This seems like some sort of misunderstanding on my part so I'm hoping the answer is simple <s>and doesn't need a MWE</s>. I've tried the docs but couldn't find a solution.

Below I add a MWE. For persistance of the question I pasted the code instead of providing a github link. This should build after creating the files and running the build.sh script.

**Desired behavior:** After choosing a zoom factor and confirming, all `InnerWidget`'s should automatically resize to fit the newly rescaled `QPixmap`'s/`QLabel`'s.

**Issue:** The `InnerWidget`'s never change size, even when calling `.resize(..` on them, why?

### MWE

> include/NestedWidgetResizeIssue_MWE.hh

```
#include <vector>

#include <QtGui/QPixmap>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QtWidgets/QScrollArea>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QFrame>

class InnerWidget : public QFrame {

    QPixmap m_img_1;
    QPixmap m_img_2;
    QLabel* m_label_1;
    QLabel* m_label_2;

    static QPixmap create_black_img();
    static void update_img_label(const QPixmap& img, QLabel* label);
    static void init_img_label(QPixmap& img, QLabel*& label);
    static void zoom_img_label(double factor, QPixmap& img, QLabel* label);

public:
    InnerWidget();

    void zoom(double factor);
};

// --------------------------------------------------

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

    QMenu* m_edit_menu;
    QAction* m_zoom_action;

    QScrollArea* m_central;
    QWidget* m_main;

    std::vector<InnerWidget*> m_entries;

    void update_max_width();

private slots:
    void zoom_inner();

public:
    MainWindow();
};
```

---

> src/NestedWidgetResizeIssue_MWE.cc

```
#include <cmath>

#include <QtGui/QPainter>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QInputDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QScrollBar>

#include <NestedWidgetResizeIssue_MWE.hh>

InnerWidget::InnerWidget() {
    setFrameShape(QFrame::Panel);
    auto* layout = new QHBoxLayout{};

    init_img_label(m_img_1, m_label_1);
    init_img_label(m_img_2, m_label_2);
    layout->addWidget(m_label_1);
    layout->addWidget(m_label_2);

    setLayout(layout);
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    adjustSize();
}

QPixmap InnerWidget::create_black_img() {
    QPixmap img(400, 400);
    QPainter p(&img);
    img.fill(QColor::fromRgb(0, 0, 0));
    return img;
}

void InnerWidget::update_img_label(const QPixmap& img, QLabel* label) {
    label->setPixmap(img);
    label->setFixedSize(img.size());
}

void InnerWidget::init_img_label(QPixmap& img, QLabel*& label) {
    img = create_black_img();
    label = new QLabel{};
    update_img_label(img, label);
}

void InnerWidget::zoom_img_label(double factor, QPixmap& img, QLabel* label) {
    img = img.scaled(img.size() * factor);
    update_img_label(img, label);
}

void InnerWidget::zoom(double factor) {
    zoom_img_label(factor, m_img_1, m_label_1);
    zoom_img_label(factor, m_img_2, m_label_2);
}

// --------------------------------------------------

MainWindow::MainWindow() :
        m_edit_menu{ menuBar()->addMenu("&Edit") },
        m_zoom_action{ new QAction{ "&Zoom" } },
        m_central{ new QScrollArea },
        m_main{ new QWidget } {

    connect(m_zoom_action, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::zoom_inner);
    m_edit_menu->addAction(m_zoom_action);

    auto* layout = new QVBoxLayout{};
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        auto* entry = new InnerWidget;
        m_entries.push_back(entry);
        layout->addWidget(entry);
    }

    m_main->setLayout(layout);
    m_central->setWidget(m_main);
    setCentralWidget(m_central);

    show();
    update_max_width();
    resize(maximumWidth(), 500);
}

void MainWindow::zoom_inner() {
    bool confirm = false;
    auto factor = QInputDialog::getDouble(this, "Zoom images", "Factor", 1.0, 0.1, 2.0, 2, &confirm, Qt::WindowFlags{}, 0.05);
    if (!confirm) return;

    for (auto* e : m_entries) {
        e->zoom(factor);
        e->adjustSize();
    }

    update_max_width();
    resize(maximumWidth(), size().height());
}

void MainWindow::update_max_width() {
    int max_entry_width = 0;
    for (const auto* e : m_entries)
        max_entry_width = std::max(max_entry_width, e->width());

    setMaximumWidth(max_entry_width + m_central->verticalScrollBar()->width() + 3);
}
```

---

> src/main.cc

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

#include <NestedWidgetResizeIssue_MWE.hh>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow win;
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

> CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Test)

add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0100 NEW)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(Test
    src/main.cc
    include/NestedWidgetResizeIssue_MWE.hh
    src/NestedWidgetResizeIssue_MWE.cc
)

target_link_libraries(Test
    Qt::Widgets
)

install(TARGETS
    Test
DESTINATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
```

---

> build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p build bin

cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal working version of this code on say Github that actually reproduces the bad behavior?

Comment: @Jellyboy I added a MWE, hopefully this helps. Unfortunately somewhat on the longer side, but there is nothing else I can really remove.